# springboot with nginx, access api 404

Tags: java, nginx, spring-boot

I start a springboot server at 8080 port by command `java -jar xxx.jar`.When I access http://localhost:8080/test/redis, it always return the correct data, like `{"a": 1}`.

But after I have set the nginx proxy config below

```
server {

    #other location config

    location /job/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

When I access http://localhost/job/test/redis, nginx directly returns 404 page. The second time I access the url, it returns the right data. And then 404 again, and then right data again, and so on. And http://localhost:8080/test/redis is always good.

I can't figured it out, why it happens like that. 
Is there anyone who can help? Thanks so much! By the way, if you need more details, just tell me in the comments

Comment: can you share with us the #other location config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh,I found out that the port for my tomcat in springboot is 8080, same as the nginx default port I have set, which has caused the strange problem.

after I changed the tomcat port to 8081, the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last `/` after `http://localhost:8080`.

### Update,

It also might be possible that the nginx proxy passes the full url, so your api is getting the whole `/job/test/redis` which doesn't exist. In that case you might need to use regex to remove the `job` part and get the rest of the url to pass with the proxy.

Comment: I remove the last / after http://localhost:8080, it does not work. The update part, I am not get it, can you give me an example, thanks

Comment: For example, someone requests `http://example.com/job/test/redix`, if I'm right you want it to proxy it to `http://localhost:8080/test/redix`, but what I think nginx is doing, is that it tries to get `http://localhost:8080/job/test/redix` from the api. You can test this out with trying to add `job` in your api resource path.

Answer (score -1):

After edit your nginx config ,do you reload nginx ?

Comment: Questions and calls for clarification should be posted as comments, not answers.

Answer (score -1):

Do you reload nginx by `nginx -s reload`?

You can check error message by `tail -f <error-log-file>`

Can you paste all of your config info, probably your request match another route which can not found response file

Comment: Questions and calls for clarification should be posted as comments, not answers.